Pass variable from one apex class to another
I have a class that retrieves a value and set its in a variable phoneNumber. I need to use that value in an apex controller that is called from a visualforce. So the case is as follows:

Class MyCTIExtensions has a method that when cases.size() > 1 it calls a visualforce page

The visualforce's controller builds a flow url to pop it up


MyCTIExtensions.cls
global class MyCTIExtensions implements purecloud.CTIExtension.ScreenPop{

    global static String phoneNumber;
    public String onScreenPop(String data){
        Map<String, Object> screenPopData = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(data);
        Map<String, Object> dataToReturn = new Map<String, Object>();
        phoneNumber = (String) screenPopData.get('searchValue');
        if (String.isNotBlank(phoneNumber)){
            String phone = '%910782475';
            List<Account> cases = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Phone LIKE :phone ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];

            if(cases.size() > 1) {
                dataToReturn.put('url','/lightning/page/recordActionFlow?lightning__flowArgs=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Phone%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22String%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22null%22%7D%5D&lightning__flowDevName=CTI_ScreenFlow_GestionDeContactosMultiples&lightning__isMandatory=false&lightning__isServiceCatalogFlow=false' /*cases.get(0).Id*/);
                return JSON.serialize(dataToReturn);
            }else if (cases.size() > 0) {
                dataToReturn.put('url',cases.get(0).Id);
                return JSON.serialize(dataToReturn);
            }
        }
        dataToReturn.put('defaultScreenPop', true);
        return JSON.serialize(dataToReturn);
    }

    public static String passPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}

FlowRedirectController
/**
@description
<Clase controladora para cubrir la visualForce RedirectToAccount>

@author Leadclic Solutions
@date 11/07/2024
*/

public class FlowRedirectController {
    public PageReference redirectToFlow() {
        // Obtén el parámetro de la página actual
        String phone =  MyCTIExtensions.passPhoneNumber(); //ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('key');
        
        // Construye el argumento del flujo con el parámetro
        String flowArgs = '[{"name":"Phone","type":"String","value":"' + phone + '"}]';
        
        // Codifica el argumento para la URL
        String encodedFlowArgs = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(flowArgs, 'UTF-8');
        
        // Construye la URL del flujo en Lightning Experience
        String flowUrl = '/lightning/page/recordActionFlow?lightning__flowDevName=CTI_ScreenFlow_GestionDeContactosMultiples&lightning__flowArgs=' + encodedFlowArgs + '&lightning__isMandatory=false&lightning__isServiceCatalogFlow=false';
        
        // Redirige a la URL del flujo en Lightning
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(flowUrl);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}

phone variable in the second class is not receiving any value.
Thanks for your help.

Creating a Visualforce page via a URL and (also a flow via a URL) will result in a new transaction being created so static state - such as MyCTIExtensions.phoneNumber - from the original transaction will not be preserved.
You will need to pass the value through both the flow URL and the Visualforce URL.
